# display:table-cell weird behaviour on adding image

Tags: html, css

I have columns with display:table-cell (to make sure they are of same height.) There is some text inside of each of the column. When I add an image to one of the cells (on top of the text), text in ALL columns is pushed down, not just in the column with the image. Is there a way to prevent text in other columns from moving?

```
<div class = 'column'>
  <h1>Some text</h1>
</div>
<div class = 'column'>
  <img src='image.png'/>
  <h1>Some other text</h1>
</div>

.column {display:table-cell}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is untested, but have you tried

```
.column {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: top;
 }
```

Honestly, I'd avoid using `display: table-cell`. Set the `height` property with css instead.

Comment: Also, why would you avoid display:table-cell? It seems to be a handy way to avoid setting rigid height on an elements in case more content is added, isnt it?

Comment: It's a hack property that doesn't render consistently across browsers. It's also not a semantic property, your content *isn't* a table cell, so it shouldn't act like one. If it is a table cell, it should already be in a table, rendering the property superflous. There are more semantic ways to achieve your desired goal.